# Creación de elemento vacio en una tabla

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Clase Usuario

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idDepartamento")
    private Departamento departamento;

    public Usuario(){
        this.departamento = new Departamento();
    }

    public Usuario(String nombre,String email){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.email = email;
    }
    //GETTERS Y SETTERS
```

Clase Departamento

```
@Entity
public class Departamento {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="departamento")
    private Collection<Usuario> usuarios;

    public Departamento(){
        this.usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    }

    public Departamento(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    //GETTERS Y SETTERS
```

Controlador de la Clase Usuario

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository personaRepo;

    @PostMapping(path = "/crear")
    public @ResponseBody Usuario addPersona(@RequestParam String nombre,
            @RequestParam String email,@RequestParam Integer idDepartamento) {
        Usuario p = new Usuario();
        p.setNombre(nombre);
        p.setEmail(email);
        p.setId(idDepartamento);
        personaRepo.save(p);
        return p;
```

}

Controlador de la Clase Departamento

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/departamento")
public class DepartamentoController {
    @Autowired
    private DepartamentoRepository departamentoRepo;

    @PostMapping(path = "/crear")
    public @ResponseBody Departamento addDepartamento(@RequestParam String nombre) {
        Departamento d = new Departamento();
        d.setNombre(nombre);
        departamentoRepo.save(d);
        return d;
    }
```

El problema es, que a la hora de crear un usuario para que pertenezca a un departamento me crea el usuario y también me crea el departamento,pero ese departamento me lo crea vació sin ningún nombre.
Lo que quiero saber es que tengo que hacer para que a la hora de crear un usuario pueda asignarle un departamento.

Comment: Cuando y dónde llamas a los controlares?

Comment: Si ese departamente ya existe en la base deberias traer ese departamento por el ID y asignarselo al usuario

Comment: Lo estoy probando mediante Postman @Csc99

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que creas una instancia de **Departamento** en el constructor de **Ususario** sin ningun tipo de dato para el mismo.
Lo que podrias hacer, despues de crear un **Usuario**, tomar con el **Get** el objeto Departamento e indicarle mediante el **setNombreDepartamento**, vale la redundancia, el nombre del departamento.

Algo asi como:

```
Usuario p = new Usuario();
p.setNombre(nombre);
p.setEmail(email);
p.setId(idDepartamento);    //Aca le asignaste el id al Usuario, no al departamento
p.getDepartamento.setNombre(nombre);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El tema es que yo el id del Departamento si se lo quiero asignar al usuario,para que pertenezca a ese Departamento.

Comment: Tenes razón, para que quede registrado la relación. Pudiste resolver el problema principal?

Comment: Si ya lo conseguí solucionar,gracias

Answer (score 1):

No deberías asignarle el id al usuario ( `p.setId(idDepartamento)` ) si está marcado como "generado automáticamente" `@GeneratedValue`. Además, ¿por qué le asignas el id del departamento al id el tercero?

Debes inyectar una referencia al `DepartamentoRepository` en la clase `UsuarioController`  y en el método `addPersona` debes hacer un llamado a un método de `DepartamentoRepository` que se llame algo así como "`findDepartamento(int idDepartamento)`", que obtenga una referencia al departamento (internamente `entityManager.find()`) para luego asignársela a la entidad Usuario. Cabe aclarar que el departamento con ese id debe ya de existir en la base de datos.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository personaRepo;
    @Autowired
    private DepartamentoRepository departamentoRepo;

    @PostMapping(path = "/crear")
    public @ResponseBody Usuario addPersona(@RequestParam String nombre,
        @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam Integer idDepartamento) {

        Departamento d = departamentoRepo.findDepartamento(idDepartamento);

        Usuario p = new Usuario();

        p.setNombre(nombre);
        p.setEmail(email);
        p.setDepartamento(d);

        personaRepo.save(p);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Podrías probar también esto:

```
Departamento d =  new Departamento();
d.setId(idDepartamento);

Usuario p = new Usuario();
p.setNombre(nombre);
p.setEmail(email);
p.setDepartamento(d);

personaRepo.save(p);
```

Sin necesidad de usar una referencia al `DepartamentoRepository` pero no estoy seguro de si JPA lo permita.